# BadMethodCallException Method [show] does not exist. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Vengo realizando un `CRUD` en `Laravel` y me esta dando un error que no se localizar ya que no tengo ninguna funcion que se llame `Show`.

Userscontroller:

```
    public function destroy($id_usuario)
{
    $user = Usuario::find($id_usuario);
    $user->delete();

    Flash::warning('Se ha eliminado ' .$user->nombre . 'de forma correcta');
    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

Index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('users.destroy', $user->id_usuario) }}" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true" onclick="return confirm('¿Seguro que quieres borrarlo')"></span></a>
```

Web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){

Route::resource('users','Userscontroller');
Route::get('users/{id_usuario}/destroy', [
    'uses' => 'UsersController@destroy',
    'as'   => 'admin.users.destroy'
  ]);

});
```

Comment: aunque creo saber dónde está el problema por favor agrega el error completo, al menos en imagen. En que ruta / contexto te aparece el error?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/E1rqz Te pongo un link donde puedes ver toda la captura al completo. Lo que mas raro me parece es que si yo entro a `controller.php`solo contiene 13 líneas y este da el error en la 82.

Comment: en qué contexto o ruta te aparece el error?

Comment: A la hora de seleccionar un botón para eliminar el usuario. Recoge la ID por que lo veo en la ruta que se supone que se dispone abrir pero lanza este error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando utilizas `Route::resource()` estás creando siete rutas a dicho controlador:

```
'index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'
```

Cada uno de estos métodos utiliza un verbo específico y un método en el controlador, como lo muestra el ejemplo de la documentación en `PhotoController`.

```
Verbo       URI                     Método  Nombre de la rta
GET         /photos                 index   photos.index
GET         /photos/create          create  photos.create
POST        /photos                 store   photos.store
GET         /photos/{photo}         show    photos.show
GET         /photos/{photo}/edit    edit    photos.edit
PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo}         update  photos.update
DELETE      /photos/{photo}         destroy photos.destroy
```

Lo que ocurre en este caso es que al hacer clic en el enlace con ruta `users/{id_usuario}/destroy` y verbo GET, Laravel está encontrando la ruta de show `/users/{id_usuario}` generada por `Route::resource()` antes que la otra que creaste.

¿Por qué ocurre esto? Las rutas en Laravel se leen en "orden" de arriba hacia abajo, y al encontrar una coincidencia de verbo y si el paramétro "parcial" o completo encaja con la ruta, la utilizará.

En otras palabras, cuando haces clic en el enlace, Laravel revisa GET y luego encuentra una coincidencia en la ruta que llama al método show gracias a `users/{id_usuario}`, y el resto de la ruta (`.../destroy`) es ignorado.

SOLUCIONES:

1. Utilizar el verbo DELETE al momento de hacer un destroy como lo sugiere Laravel, para esto harías un llamado al enlace con un formulario, algo así:

   ```
   {!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id_usuario], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
     {!! Form::submit('Eliminar') !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
   ```
2. Cambiar de orden las rutas para que Laravel encuentre primero tu ruta que la de resource:

   ```
   Route::get('users/{id_usuario}/destroy', [
       'uses' => 'UsersController@destroy',
       'as'   => 'admin.users.destroy'
   ]);
   Route::resource('users','Userscontroller');
   ```
3. Decirle a Laravel que no genera la ruta que utiliza el método show:

   ```
   Route::resource('users','Userscontroller', ['except' => ['destroy', 'show']]);
   ```

Más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Acabo de probar las tres maneras, y sigue dando el error en `show`,voy a mirar la documentación a ver. siento la tardazna encontestar.

Comment: Tal vez debas limpiar la caché de rutas de Laravel.

Comment: Fui probando uno a uno todos los metodos mientras limpiaba la caché de rutas del Laravel, y sigue sin funcionar, en la ruta se ve que coge la `ID`pero no elimina nada, pero ahora tampoco da error solo se actualiza la página añadiendole en la ruta la `ID`y ya esta.

Comment: Vale ya se por que ahora no aparece el error, por que declare la `public function show`la elimino y muestra de nuevo el mismo error.

Comment: Por lo que me cuentas, debería funcionar el tercer método, ¿el controlador se llama `Userscontroller` y no `UsersController`? Otra cosa muy pequeña que veo es que la ruta que defines se llama `admin.users.destroy` pero en el enlace que defines llamas a `users.destroy`

Comment: revisa por favor la modificación que hice al tercer método

Comment: Lo modifique todo a `UsersController` para que no haya error. Y lo otro es que si pongo àdmin.users.destroy me salta este error, `Route [admin.users.index] not defined.` Y es que en el que èdito`pongo solo ùsers.destroy, y funciona

Comment: Revise todas las rutas, para que quedaran en `users.destroy`y ya funciona todo correctamente, no se por que en edit no me estaba pasando eso, pero muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.